# Format numeric string with comma separator for indian numbering system

Tags: c#, .net

I have a number value in `string` as

```
string strNum = "12345678.90";
```

I want to format it with comma separator using `regex` in `String.Format()`

On using `"{0:n0}"` format in

```
String.Format("{0:n0}", Convert.ToDouble(strNum));
```

it is giving me output as `"12,345,679"`

Instead of this i want output as `"1,23,45,678.90"`. After thousand's place i want comma separator after 2 digits each for lakhs, crores and so on

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var s = String.Format(new CultureInfo( "en-IN", false ), "{0:n}", Convert.ToDouble("12345678.90"));
```

Comment: It gives me output as "12,34,56,79", but required output is "1,23,45,678.90"

Comment: Edited. If you use the right culture you don't need to set the NumberGroupSizes

Answer (score 2):

For such a typical way I would write a specialized function that transforms a number into the string you propose.

I even would suggest to make the item a class, having the value represented as float or by different items like lakhs, crores etc.

And then make a ToString method to output it the way you want.

Example (not tested):

```
class SpecialNumber
{
    int _lakhs;
    int _crores;
    int _another_unit;
    int _rest;

    public SpecialNumber(int lakhs, int crores, int another_unit, int rest)
    {
         _lakhs = lakhs;
         _crores = crores;
         _another_unit = another_unit;
         _rest = rest;
    }

    public string ToString()
    {
         // Check for exact formatting.
         return String.Format("{0:2},{1:2},{2:3}.{0:2}", 
          _laksh, _crores, _another_unit, _rest);
    }
```

Comment: But i am looking for a direct approach if possible, otherwise transformation using a function, I have already done.

Comment: What do you mean by direct approach? What would be your ideal solution to this? (Not being sarcastic, genuinely curious what you're after).

Comment: By direct approach, I mean using regex expression to format it or any combination of inbuilt string functions...

Answer (score 1):

With this code you can change an amount string to Indian standard comma separated value; use culture `"hi-IN"` and the format `"{0:#,0.00}"`
here `strNum` is my string value amount.

```
string.Format( System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hi-IN"), "{0:#,0.00}", Convert.ToDouble(strNum)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be to use the String.Format along with '#' as such:

```
String.Format(0:##,##,##,##,##,###.##)
```

The '#' is a digit placeholder and will not show a zero (or anything else) if the number is not large enough.

See [MSDN custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to format according to hindi culture.
so set your culture, or provide the culture to `String.Format`, like

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "<yourculture>" ), "{0:n}", Convert.ToDouble(strNum));
```